# Save CSV file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am able to change the data to lowercase and remove all the punctuation but I have trouble saving the corrected data in CSV file.

```
import csv
import re
import os

input_file=raw_input("Name of the CSV file:")
output_file=raw_input("Output Name:")


reg_test=input_file
result = ''

with open(input_file,'r') as csvfile:
  with open(output_file,'w') as csv_out_file:
  filereader = csv.reader(csvfile)
  filewriter =csv.writer(csv_out_file)
  for row in filereader:
     row = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', str(row))
     result += row + ','

lower = (result).lower()
csvfile.close()
csv_out_file.close()
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong and you kind of misunderstood the way the `with` statement works.

Comment: You don't have to nest `with` statements like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to close the files, this is done automatically after the context of the with statement is over and you have to actually write something after you create the `csv.writer`, e.g. with `writerow`:

```
import csv
import re

input_file = 'in.csv'
output_file = 'out.csv'

with open(input_file, 'r') as csvfile, open(output_file, 'w') as csv_out_file:
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    filewriter = csv.writer(csv_out_file)
    for row in filereader:
        new_row = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', str(row))  # manipulate the row
        filewriter.writerow([new_row.lower()])  # write the new row to the out file

# the files are closed automatically after the context of the with statement is over
```

This saves the manipulated content of the first csv file to the second.

Comment: Thank you it works! Where  should i put if i want to remove punctuation and change all texts to lowercase in CSV/

Comment: Add your code to the line with the comment `# do something with that row`

Comment: i tried. but the result will string each letters. for example it should be yellow but it is shown as "Y , E ,L,L,O,W"

Comment: Do you mind edit the code telling how should i put .lower() and row = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', str(row))

Comment: What is in your csv file and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: my CSV file consist of texts. I actually doing data mining and i am at the step of data cleaning. I am suppose to change all the texts to lowercase and remove all the punctuation.

Comment: For example: line one is " The concert is great!" , line 2 is " THE CONCERT IS GREAT!@$$". i now have to clean the texts to : "the concert is great"

Comment: tokenizing and stopwords will be after this process

Comment: I updated the answer. But your regex removes spaces as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate it!

Comment: All my output have t to the output. Like for example, tthe , tconcert tis tgreat! please help